# How to add an attribute other than style attributes to css?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a html/css/javascript program which you can solve sudokus that the program generates, like an online puzzle book. Because of this, I have a lot if `<input />` tags (81 to be precise) for unique id's for each one. But I have also had to write the `maxlength` attribute for each `<input />` tag that I wrote.

I am wondering if you can do this in css instead. Can you have attributes other that style attributes (such as `border` or `margin`) in CSS? If so, how do you reference them? I've tried to type it directly in, but it appears that it does not exist.

My examplar input tag: `<input id="00" type="text" onclick="checkIfBold('00')" maxlength="1"/>`

The CSS for the tag:

```
input {
    border: 0px solid #000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

My aim is to set the `maxlength` attribute of the `<input />` element by using CSS.

Note that I am not just asking about this specific attribute, I am asking how to reference any other html attribute in css (if possible)?

Comment: Are you asking, for example, how to set the max length for all inputs via CSS instead of inline? Since you're using Javascript, would a JS/jQuery solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, but I'd rather it be using CSS.

Comment: Well, I don't think it's possible using CSS, and if it is, it's going to be some weird hack that probably won't work in all browsers and will be extremely difficult to employ... I'm posting a jQuery solution below that will work just fine for you though.

Comment: It seems your answer to my comment and the wording in post are a little conflicting. Are you trying to set an element's attribute, or are you trying to style an element with a specific attribute value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I specify maxlength in css?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363030/can-i-specify-maxlength-in-css)

Comment: I'm trying to set an element's attribute, but not in HTML, in CSS. And preferably not in Javascript (never used jQuery before)

Comment: Ok, well you're out of luck with CSS so this might be a good opportunity to learn the basics of jQuery, it's pretty easy to learn so you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment above:

You can't do this with CSS, but it's very simple to do with jQuery...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input").attr('maxlength','1');
});
```

Switch out the `'1'` with whatever number you want the maxlength to be and you can also switch out `'maxlength'` with any other attribute you want to target.

Comment: OK, well thank you for your help. I guess I will just have to use Javascript, or just type in into each element individually.

Answer (score 5):

You can't. CSS is for defining how things should *look*. `maxlength` defines how the input *works*. `maxlength` defines functionality. If you want to give an input a certain (visual) size, use the `width` CSS property.

Comment: sry, i miss understood the question **getting red**

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with CSS. You could use javascript / jQuery.

Here is an example for jQuery:

```
$('input[type="text"]').attr('maxlength', '1');
```

Comment: I think the question is about getting the (false) idea that every attribute can or should be defined in CSS. Since that is not possible, you might as well add the attributes in HTML. No need to write Javascript for it, especially if those 81 inputs are generated by a server side script. But it's nice to know how. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol I agree there is no *need* for JS, but since it seems OP's goal is to save time/effort in manually typing (copy/pasting) the maxlength attributes for each element, this answer will ultimately do that...

Comment: I wouldn't recommend doing that via Javascript either, but as you pointed out via server side script. But I tried helping the OP with his question and showing him a quick client side solution, as he tried to approach it also client side with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets to select attributes in CSS. Keep in mind that you don't have a lot of leeway here. Basically, you can say:

```
[border]{
  /*styles for elements with a border*/
}
```

or

```
[border=1px solid black]{
  /*styles for elements with a border of EXACTLY 1px solid black, in that order*/
}
```

there are no wildcards or partial matches. You will likely Javascript to select more specifically, or to alter anything other than styles.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the question. OP doesn't want to *select* elements with specific attributes, but *set* those attributes .

Comment: Ah - i see. Fundamental understanding issue then. Style attributes are css and css is style attributes, nothing more.

Comment: Yeah, and you may not have misunderstood... After I posted my comment, I went a re-read OP's question and it isn't too clear so you may be on the mark... Just one of those questions I guess!